# スプレッドシートから情報取得関数について

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

自作関数にてURLから取得するようにしたんですが
以下の物は出来たのですが、それ以外に最終更新者、最終更新日を取得したいと思っています。
それとURLと紐づけされたスクリプトエディタ？プロジェクトの中の○○○.gsのソースコードを抜き出し、そこに記載されいるURLの一部を抜き出したいのですが可能でしょうか？

ドキュメント名取得関数

```
function getDocumentName(url) {
    var URLNum = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    return(URLNum.getName());
}
```

ドキュメント所有者取得関数

```
function getDocumentOwner(url) {
    var URLNum = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    return(URLNum.getOwner().getEmail());
}
```

Comment: 最終更新者、最終更新日の情報だけでもあればありがたいです。

Comment: 実施してみましたが、
アドイン管理者権限により、
DriveApp.getFileByIdは使用できませんでした。

上位の権限ではない無理なのでしょうね。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpreadSheet API内には見つかりませんでしたね・・・
最終更新日時に関してはDriveAppsAPIを併用してこんな感じでしょうか

```
id = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getId();
last = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getLastUpdated();
```

最終日時に関してはAppsScript内には見つけられませんでした。
REST経由でとる方法なら以下が紹介されていますが・・・
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017673/google-apps-script-drive-file-how-to-get-user-who-last-modified-file